# AWS Nuke script not working, access denied error

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudtrail

I am trying to clean up resources for my organization account using this AWS-Nuke [Script](https://github.com/1Strategy/automated-aws-multi-account-cleanup)

Here, How I have done using AWS Console,

1. I have created an organization and added few member accounts in it.
2. From Github repository, In aws-nuke-config.yaml , I have added my main account ID in blacklist.
3. Then Uploaded this file in S3 Bucket.
4. Created a stack using NukeStack.yaml and given ParentOuId from Organization
5. Bucket Name mytestbucket1234
6. AssumeRoleName as NukeRole

After this in Cloud Watch I modified schedule for 10minutes, In CloudTrail it says StartBuild AccessDenied.

```
"errorCode": "AccessDenied",
"errorMessage": "User: arn:aws:sts::myAccountID:assumed-role/CloudWatchNukeScriptSchedule-nuke/91b9068c9b993c148bc0a29fb9275767 is not authorized to perform: codebuild:StartBuild on resource: arn:aws:codebuild:us-east-2:myAccountID:project/AccountNuker-nuke",
```

Can anyone tell me where I am missing in the setup?

Comment: Reading the YAML policy at that GitHub repo, it indicates `us-west-2` throughout. I would assume that you need to change this to `*` for all regions or specifically set the region that you want (`us-east-2`).

Comment: error is gone but script still not working like not cleaning resources..

Comment: Because of the destructive nature of this tool, its default operation does not actually nuke resources You need to include `--no-dry-run`.

Comment: still not working, I think some issue with setup

Comment: That looks like a very dangerous tool. If you lack the knowledge to configure it, I would advise against using it.